# Maven EAR plugin: Adding generated resources

Tags: maven, ear, maven-resources-plugin, maven-ear-plugin

In a custom Maven plugin, I add a file as resource by using the `addResource` of `MavenProject`.

This works well for JAR projects, but for EARs, I see that the relevant file is copied to `target/classes` and then ignored. It is not present in the EAR.

There is an earSourceDirectory property which I can probably use to "trick" Maven by setting it to `target/classes` but it seems like the wrong way.

How can I handle generated resources that should be packed into an EAR?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of generated resources you need to add ? I suppose you don't put them into the correct locations?

Comment: @khmarbaise During the build, we generate a properties file (with various build properties) inside our own Maven plugin. This file should be put into the artifact (at the top level). For that, we use `addResource`. This works for jars, but not for ears. So this is about a properties file that is generated in a Maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven EAR plugin completely disregard all of the "resources" directories that can be set up for a given artifact. Instead, as you mentioned, it solely relies on the directory referenced by the `earSourceDirectory` property, `src/main/application` being the default value. (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#earSourceDirectory)

Therefore, you have two choices: either change that property value to point to `target/classes` as you proposed, or generate your files (as we did for one project) under `src/main/application` and then they will automatically be picked up by maven-ear-plugin.

Comment: Generating files outside `target` during the build seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: @JFMeier we actually generate those in the `generate-resources` phase, which is directly intended for that purpose (that is generate resources before getting them in the actual artifact)

Comment: But when you generate resources, you do not write them to `src/main/resources`, do you? You would write them to the `target` directory (or a subdirectory thereof).

Comment: We do generate those to `src/main/resources` and ignore those by mean of an expression in `.gitignore`; in fact I did some research and a similar case was discussed and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245051/6131265

Comment: Thank you, but writing to `src/main/resources` during the build is a dangerous thing. It will not be tidied up when calling `mvn clean`, developers might try to change it by hand, it may end up in SVN accidentally etc. This is no option for me.

Comment: Why don't you also configure the maven clean plugin as well then? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html#filesets

Comment: Because I try to keep with the defaults as much as possible. Special cases and non-standard directories break expectations.